# How to do a conditional click?

Tags: javascript, selenium

Using the seleniumIDE, with additional javascript as needed.

I only want to go to the url if the button exists.

The button says 'proceed', the url is /reports/start

I have tried:

```
store   //a[text()='start']/@href  startButtonURL
store   javascript{if (startButton != null) {location.href=${startButtonURL}}}  ignore_me_var
```

but the seleniumIDE window itself gets closed, and I can't get the window with the location to be the selenium window that is being used by the rest of the test suite.  Everything I've tried ends up with a new window.

Comment: Did you try the [Flow control plugin](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) for IDE? It enables you to use conditionals on their own...

Comment: hmm, that's tempting.  Do you know what will happen to test cases that use it if I export them to rspec (or another language format).  I'm generally trying to stay away from plugins becuase of this (potential) issue.

Comment: No, you're right. I have no idea what would happen. One hopes it would turn out OK, but ... I woudn't count on it :(.

Comment: Update: I have found that even `javascript{window.location.replace('http://google.com') }` closes my seleniumIDE window and replaces it with google but doesn't affect the actual window where the tests themselves were running.